# ¿Porque usar FROM con Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

Llevo un tiempo trabajando con Hibernate y no entiendo porque se complican a la hora de hacer las consultas a bbdd:

```
Root<Foo> fooRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Foo.class);
Join<Foo, Foo1> foo1 = fooRoot.join("foo1", JoinType.LEFT);
```

Cuando puedes simplemente:

```
criteriaQuery.from(Foo.class).list();
```

Que ventajas aporta el ir creando los Join a mano cuando ya tienes definidos en tu fichero de configuración o anotaciones como se relacionan las entidades de tu modelo.
Si es por rendimiento, hibernate no recupera los datos hasta que accedes expresamente a esos datos.

Gracias por las respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, técnicamente no es Hibernate, es JPA (aunque uses Hibernate como implementaciónate, te tiene que funcionar con cualquier otra implementación de JPA).

En cuanto a la cuestión, estás comparando dos situaciones distintas; con la primera tienes una referencia a la entidad `Foo1` que puedes usar para añadir restricciones.

```
Root<Foo> fooRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Foo.class);
Join<Foo, Foo1> foo1 = fooRoot.join("foo1", JoinType.LEFT);
ParameterExpression<Integer> parameterExpression = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Integer.class);
criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.gt(foo1.get("atributoDeFoo1"), 50));
```

Si no tienes que filtrar por la entidad navegada, no necesitas el `Join`.